# Counting the number of injections and surjections

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $A$ be a set with $n$ elements and $B$ bet a set with $n+1$ elements.

In order to be injective, for each $b \in B$ there is exactly one $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. I'm under the impression that this comes out to $\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1-n)!}=(n+1)!$.  However, I'm worried that I'm overcounting.

Let $A$ be a set with $n+1$ elements and $B$ bet a set with $n$ elements.

This one I'm a bit more worried about.  It seems like for each choice of $b$, there is at most $n+1$ elements to be choosen from $A$.  It seems like there are at most $(n+1)^n$ onto functions.

Comment: For the number of injective maps, $A$ to $B$, where $A$ has $n$ elements and $B$ has $n+1$, the answer is indeed $(n+1)!$, you are not overcounting.

Comment: Isn't the injection a function where for each $b \in B$ there is AT MOST one $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$?

Comment: @pkacprzak Is right, the question should be restated to say bijection (1-to-1 mapping between two sets) rather than injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For injectivity you are correct.  Another way of getting that number is you have $n + 1$ choices for which element of $B$ to miss, and there are $n!$ choices for how to order the $n$ elements we hit (imagine $A = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$).

For surjectivity there can be at most $1$ collision.  So there are ${n + 1} \choose 2$ choices for the collision and then $n!$ ways to order the $n$-groups left over (we combine the two that map to the same element onto one "group").  This gives ${{n + 1} \choose 2}\cdot n! = \frac{1}{2}n\cdot(n+1)!$.

Comment: Just one question, what do you mean at most one collision?

Comment: There can be at most one pair $\{x, y\}$ such that $x \neq y$ but $f(x) = f(y)$.